# how to update a field based on another field in orders table after 120 mintutes passed?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have orders table. I want to update the stage field after 120 minutes from the time driver received the order.

This is my code and attempt:

```
$minuts =120 ;


        $orders = Order::where('stage',8)->where('driver_received_time','<',Carbon::now()->addMinutes($minuts))->get();
        $i = 0 ;
        foreach ($orders as $order)
        {

                $order->update(['stage'=>9]);
                $driver = Driver::find($order->driver_id);
                if ($driver->engaged == 1)
                {
                    $driver->engaged = 0;
                    $driver->save();
                }
                $i++;

        }
```

```
Orders Table:

------
orders
------
stage
driver_received_time
```

Comment: unclear of what you are asking, also add what have you tried so far and if any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the `$orders` then for each `$order` you calculate the *minutes* passed:

```
 $orders = Order::where('stage',8)->get();
    $i = 0 ;
    foreach ($orders as $order)
    {
       $diff_in_minutes = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($order->driver_received_time);

        if($diff_in_minutes > 120){

            $order->update(['stage'=>9]);
            $driver = Driver::find($order->driver_id);
            if ($driver->engaged == 1)
            {
                $driver->engaged = 0;
                $driver->save();
            }
            $i++;
        }

    }
```